# Trying to escape URI while posting via ajax to database. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, escaping

I'm grabbing the src attribute from an image tag and posting it to my database via an ajax call which is then used to form an XML file. I really need to escape this image path and seem to be quite stumped on how to do this. Trying to use the encodeURIComponent without much luck. Below is my code. Thanks for any help!

```
$('.drag-elem').each(function () {
    var xml = '<clother><id>' + $(this).children('img').attr('class') + 
        '</id><title>' + $(this).children('img').attr('alt') + '</title><z-index>' +
        $(this).css('z-index') + '</z-index><top>' + $(this).css('top') + 
        '</top><left>' + $(this).css('left') + '</left><file>' + 
        encodeURIComponent($(this).children('img').attr('src')) +
        '</file></clother>';
});
```

Comment: What does the output look like?

Comment: The output would be this. As you can see from the <file> node the img URL is not very XML friendly

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<clothing>
  <clother>
    <id>product-5316</id>
    <title>Amber Tigress Shades</title>
    <z-index>2</z-index>
    <top>355px</top>
    <left>113px</left>
    <file>http://www.domain.com/images/thumb/phpThumb.php?src=http://www.domain.com/uploads/products/712SP_GLD.jpg&w=95&h=98&q=90&far=C&bg=FFFFFF</file>
  </clother>
</clothing>`

Comment: From where does that output come from? PHP or JS?

Comment: something is off because `encodeUrlComponent('http://www.domain.com/images/thumb/phpThumb.php?src=http://www.domain.com/‌​uploads/products/712SP_GLD.jpg&w=95&h=98&q=90&far=C&bg=FFFFFF')` equals  `"http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.com%2Fimages%2Fthumb%2FphpThumb.php%3Fsrc%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.com%2F%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Buploads%2Fproducts%2F712SP_GLD.jpg%26w%3D95%26h%3D98%26q%3D90%26far%3DC%26bg%3DFFFFFF"`

Comment: Dor, the image src is posted via javascript to a .php file wich then inserts the data into the database. 

Joey, yes. This is correct, so where could I be going wrong here?

Comment: Show us the raw code. What happens when you write `alert($(this).children('img').attr('src'))` immediately after the line `$('.drag-elem').each(function () {` ?

Comment: It comes back and says `http://www.domain.com/images/thumb/phpThumb.php?src=http://www.domain.com/uploads/products/48581.jpg&w=95&h=98&q=90&far=C&bg=FFFFFF`

Comment: I can't seem to show you all the raw code... not enough comment room even after minifying it. Grr.

Answer (score 1):

You must use encodeURI. Because encodeURIComponent isn´t good for full paths.

---

Try to use a xml encode function  (encodeXml) clearing your xml from amps:

```
var xml_special_to_escaped_one_map = {
'&': '&amp;',
'"': '&quot;',
'<': '&lt;',
'>': '&gt;'
};

var escaped_one_to_xml_special_map = {
'&amp;': '&',
'&quot;': '"',
'&lt;': '<',
'&gt;': '>'
};

function encodeXml(string) {
return string.replace(/([\&"<>])/g, function(str, item) {
return xml_special_to_escaped_one_map[item];
});
};

function decodeXml(string) {
return string.replace(/(&quot;|&lt;|&gt;|&amp;)/g,
function(str, item) {
return escaped_one_to_xml_special_map[item];
});
}
```

From here: http://dracoblue.net/dev/encodedecode-special-xml-characters-in-javascript/155/

Comment: I just tried this out using encodeURI and the whole process is killed the moment it hit's the ampersand &. Nothing is posted after that.

Answer (score 0):

hard to say since it looks all good to me. tried reproducing and is fine in my browser.

try changing javascript library (jquery?) and try another browser. And try breaking down the string to variables to nail the problem.